# Json loading with gremlin server in titan graph database

Tags: java, titan, gremlin

I am trying to load Json file into the Titan graph database using gremlin query     I got the following queries

```
   graph = TitanFactory.open('conf/titan-cassandra-es.properties')
   g = graph.traversal()
   g.loadGraphSON('tjson.json.json')
```

I am getting error like

> No signature of method:
>   org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.GraphTraversalSource.loadGraphSon()
>   is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values:
>   [tjson.json]

**question is : How to load the Json file**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you are using a newer version of Titan - meaning 1.0 or greater. If so, that syntax - `g.loadGraphSON('tjson.json.json')` is no longer supported. That's the old TinkerPop 2.x syntax. Titan 1.0 and greater supports TinkerPop 3.x. You can read about the revised syntax [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#graphson-reader-writer) but it basically looks like this now:

```
graph.io(IoCore.graphson()).readGraph("graphson-file.json");
```

Comment: I tried to load json file with above query but I am getting following error

Comment: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY token.                                                                                                                          My json file sample is as follows.                                                                            [{"TRANSACTION DATE":"11/19/2016","IFSC CODE":"ICIC0004351","AMOUNT":"102453","ACCOUNT":"9111115461"}]

Comment: If that is your JSON file then the problem is that you are not conforming to what the `GraphSONReader` is expecting as the format. The reader does not take arbitrary JSON. Perhaps [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32907983/1831717) will help you understand the formatting better.

Comment: I have graphjson like this :            {"id":0,"label":"Person","outE":{"transfer":[{"id":0,"inV":"ICIC0000008-805000017","properties":{"amount":"228786690"}}]},"properties":{"name":[{"id":0,"value":"SBIN0000196-33502796303"}]}                                             I am trying to load this into titan using following query                             graph.io(IoCore.graphson()).readGraph("test.json")                               I am getting error as Invalid Vertex:Null

Comment: you have the `inV` as a vertex that does not have a valid identifier. it needs to map to a vertex id as given by "id" (like you have in that example the "id" is "0")

Comment: ya stefan. according to your suggestion I changed my json file as follows

Comment: {"id":0,"label":"Person","outE":{"transfer":[{"id":0,"inV":1,"properties":{"amount":"228786690"}}]},"properties":{"name":[{"id":0,"value":"SBIN0000196-33502796303"}]},"id":2,"label":"Person","outE":{"transfer":[{"id":1,"inV":3,"properties":{"amount":"89836806"}}]},"properties":{"name":[{"id":1,"value":"HDFC0000240-600000000000"}]},"id":4,"label":"Person","outE":{"transfer":[{"id":2,"inV":5,"properties":{"amount":"81974217"}}]},"properties":{"name":[{"id":2,"value":"SBIN0000196-33502796303"}]}}

Comment: I am getting the error that value[S‌​BIN0000196-335027963‌​03] not satify the unique constraint.   in this json file S‌​BIN0000196-335027963‌​03 is repeated with different Id. when second time this is passed it is trying to add it as a vertex with a different edge property.

Comment: how to not add duplicate value again.

Comment: `readGraph()` is meant to load to an empty graph not one with data in it. If you want to read to a graph that has data in it already you would need to use `readVertices()` and supply "attach" functions for how you would detect an existing vertex. Note that the `Attachable.Method` class has some ready made functions that can help with that.

Comment: @ArundhathiD it would be better if you edit your original question rather than carry on in the comments

Comment: @JasonPlurad My first question was basic question. I am new to the gremlin, since no proper documentation available to me that is why I asked. second problem was even I got proper query from Stefan also still I was not able to load json file. Then stefan replied with proper answer again. since I am getting the error sequentially I am commenting there.

Comment: @stephenmallette could please tell me the any proper documentation or book on tinker top and gremlin queries. it will be helpful for my learning.

Comment: You should look at the [reference documentation](http://tinkerpop.apach.org/docs/current/reference) and [the tutorials](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/) - take care to read the version of the docs specific to the version you are using. replace "current" in the URL with your specific version. If you are using 3.1.3, then just replace it