# Loading Graphson into Titan graph database

Tags: java, json, titan, gremlin

I have graphjson like this :

```
{
   "id": 0,
   "label": "Person",
   "outE": {
      "transfer": [
         {
            "id": 0,
            "inV": "ICIC0000008-805000017",
            "properties": {
               "amount": "228786690"
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "properties": {
      "name": [
         {
            "id": 0,
            "value": "SBIN0000196-33502796303"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I am trying to load this into titan using following query:                         `graph.io(IoCore.graphson()).readGraph("test.json")`

However, I am getting error: `Invalid Vertex:Null`

Comment: Why all your id is 0 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Json loading with gremlin server in titan graph database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44039683/json-loading-with-gremlin-server-in-titan-graph-database)